# onopen not responding in angular websocket

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, websocket, mean-stack

I'm new to websockets and i'm simply trying to get the server to respond when opening my app in the browser, but the `connection.onopen` is not responding as expected. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
angular.module('app')
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    var url = 'ws://localhost:3000'
    var connection = new WebSocket(url)

    connection.onopen = function () {
        console.log('WebSocket connected')
    }
})
```

Comment: have you injected ['ngWebSocket'] in your module.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was expecting it to print to my terminal console where I ran the server, but it printed out to the browser console in dev tools.